# Rest API using nodejs express

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am working on a Login api.

Backend: Node.JS
Datastore: MongoDB

I am getting `TypeError`

`app.js`:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());

var db = require('./db')
db.connect(() => {
  app.listen(3000, function (){
      console.log(`Listening`);
  });
});


const loginRoute = require('./routes/login');
app.use('/login', loginRoute);
```

Router - `login.js`

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const loginSchema = require('../models/LoginSchema');
const db = require('../db');

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    db.collection('login').find({}, function (err, result) {
        console.log(result);
        res.send('We are at login api'+result);
    });
});

router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    const logindata = new loginSchema({
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password
    });
    db.collection('login').insert(logindata, function(err, data) {
        res.json(data);
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

**Schema :** `loginschema.js`

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const loginschema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type : String
    },
    email: {
        type : String,
        required : true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        require: true
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('login', loginschema);
```

**MongoDB connection :** `db.js`

```
const mongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const mongoDbUrl = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017';
let db;

function connect(callback){
    mongoClient.connect(mongoDbUrl, { useUnifiedTopology: true }, (err, client) => {
        db = client.db('test');
        callback();
    });
}
function get(){
    return db;
}

function close(){
  db.close();
}

module.exports = {
    connect,
    get,
    close
};
```

This is the error that I am getting:

```
TypeError: db.collection is not a function  
    at C:\rest-api\routes\login.js:19:8  
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\rest-api\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)  
    at next (C:\rest-api\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)  
    at Route.dispatch (C:\rest-api\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)  
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\rest-api\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)  
    at C:\rest-api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22  
    at Function.process_params (C:\rest-api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)  
    at next (C:\rest-api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)  
    at Function.handle (C:\rest-api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)  
    at router (C:\rest-api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)  
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\rest-api\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)  
    at trim_prefix (C:\rest-api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)  
    at C:\rest-api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7  
    at Function.process_params (C:\rest-api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)  
    at next (C:\rest-api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)  
    at C:\rest-api\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:130:5
```

Help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You are calling `db.collection` but `collection` is not exported in `db.js`

Comment: @ShreyasHeda Where do you get that "collection() " would be a member of the mongodb connection ? It clearly isn't. Remember you are using "mongoose" , not the native mongodb driver. This and what Evert said

Comment: @ShreyasHeda Please take a look at my answer below, let me know if it helps !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use Mongoose Model directly to get Documents

Instead of

```js
db.collection('login').find({}, function (err, result) {

});
// This will fail since 'collection' is not exported by your db.js
```

try using your Mongoose Model directly like :

```js
// find all Login Documents 
loginSchema.find({}, function (err, result) {

});
```

```js
// create a new document
const newlogin = new loginSchema(); 
newlogin.save((err, saveddoc) => {

});
```

Comment: i tried your solution.. but i am not getting any response. 
in postman it says : Could not get any response

Comment: If result is empty ... this could mean there are no documents in the logins collection

Comment: i have two records inside login collection

Comment: Curious, did you use the mongoose model to create the documents as in `new loginSchema()` ? ... by default if the model is called "Login" the collection would be called "Logins" (plural) ... and would be automatically created.

Comment: no.. i did not use loginSchema to create document!!  i created manually!!

Comment: I updated my answer below to show how you create the document using the loginSchema Model . Try to create a bunch of documents using this method, and if there are no errors, try using the `find` method again afterwards. I am sure there is a solution to this.

Comment: Glad I could help @ShreyasHeda , please accept my answer if it helped you !

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wring API. `.find(..)` is for Mongoose and you are using it for database configuration `db.collection(..)`

See modified `app.js`:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const loginSchema = require('../models/login');
const db = require('../db');

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    loginSchema.find({}, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Error:", err);
    }
    else{
     res.send('We are at login api'+result);
    }   
    });
});

router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    const logindata = new loginSchema({
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password
    });
    loginSchema.insert(logindata, function(err, data) {
        res.json(data);
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

db.collection() is a method provided with the mongo shell.

You can use the mongoose library to solve your issue.